# Resolve function not being injected in controller [Angular JS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, controllers

```
angular
  .module('madkoffeeFrontendApp', [])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/articles.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
          articles: function(articleService,$q) {
          //  return articleService.getArticles();
            return 'boo';
          }
        }
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

My above code contains the resolve.

```
  angular.module('madkoffeeFrontendApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope, articles) {
      console.log(articles);
  }]);
```

When I tried to inject articles in the array as shown below, it gives an error but as far as I know that's the correct way to inject a resolve function:

```
  angular.module('madkoffeeFrontendApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','articles',
    function($scope, articles) {
      console.log(articles);
  }]);
```

My articles resolve function is not being injected. I tried returning just a string (example: 'boo') as shown to test if articles dependency works or not, and it doesn't i.e. it returns undefined. What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you minifying?  If so then you need to wrap your resolve function in `[arcticleService, $q, function(articleService, $q){ . . . }]`

Comment: I mistyped earlier.  If minifying, wrap your resolve function like so `['arcticleService', '$q', function(articleService, $q){ . . . }]`

Comment: Can you write the resolve function again? I'm a bit confused about wrapping it like that^

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or PlunkR demonstrating your problem? I would think your second definition of MainCtrl above should work but it is difficult to see why it isn't without examining an example that reproduces your error

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Plunker to demonstrate the resolve message. As you'll see in the example, it's the same structure as the code you posted and should work fine.

Click the about page to see the resolve message.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FomhxYIra5GI7nm1KpGb?p=preview

Code:

```
var resolveTestApp = angular.module('resolveTestApp', ['ngRoute']);

    resolveTestApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController',
            resolve: {
              resolveMessage: function() {
                return 'This is the resolve message';
              }
            }
        })

});

resolveTestApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

resolveTestApp.controller('aboutController', ['$scope', 'resolveMessage', function($scope, resolveMessage) {
  $scope.message = resolveMessage;
}]
);
```

It may be the version of Angular you're using or a problem when you're minifying your code.

Comment: Yes i'm using the latest version. Tried your code, when I try to do this:  `['$scope', 'resolveMessage', `.. I get an injection error.